# .Net Solution with c# and visual basic projects

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, solution

I have a .Net solution with 5 projects in c# and one in visual basic. I want to know  whether there would be a gain of performance to convert my visual basic project to C# in the day to day while I compile my solution.

Comment: Sorry, do you asking about a performance of compilation ?

Comment: The name of the language is c#

Comment: Just a side note, if you're consuming methods from the C# assemblies in the VB one remember that C# is case sensitive, whilst VB isn't, so avoid creating methods, members nor properties whose names only vary in case.

Comment: It's all about compile time execution and I'm very satisfy with answers below. I forgot to mention that the vb projet is a projet that the entire code is auto-generated and mark as DebuggerStepThroughAttribute. For this reason, my only constraint while programming was about the time it take to compile. Thank you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Visual Basic and C# projects both compile very quickly - so there is likely to be little difference.  Also, since they both compile to the same or similar IL, there will be little difference in runtime performance.

However, there may be an advantage in terms of long term maintainability.  Having a single language code base is often easier to maintain over time, especially with multiple developers.

Comment: I think the question is too context specific. It depends what is about VB.NET code and what is about C# code, actually.

Comment: There is no direct performance boost, or loss. Where your going to see changes is based on how it's coded. With newer computers, the CPU's are getting smarter, and able to predict certain branches. So even if the IL puts things in different order, the CPU might switch it around.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any performance gain in the compilation process at all it will be negligible (you are talking about compilation time right?) and not worth the conversion time, risk and headache. Unless you have a better reason for converting then in this case it's likely best to [let sleeping dogs lie](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/let+sleeping+dogs+lie.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure not.
All your code from VB and C# is compiled into CIL(formerly MSIL).